# INSERTING ELEMENT IN STACK

Tags: c, stack

I am learning data structure. Now I came to point where I using C for inserting an element in the stack. This code of mine is working good. But the problem is if I want to push the next number. It gets inserted in [i] value of stack.But when i want to insert new element, instead of getting [i+1] location it overwrites [i]  value. When i call this function again only then it inserts the next value to stack[i+1].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CAPACITY 5

int element;
int top = -1;
int stack[CAPACITY];
int isfull() {
    if(top==CAPACITY-1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}

int push(int element) {
    if(isfull()){
        printf("STACK IS FULL");
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = element;
        printf("DONE ");
    }
}
int main(){
    scanf("%d", &element);
    push(element);

    for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++){
        printf("\n%d\n", stack[i]);
    }
}
```

On first input

```
DONE 
41

0

0

0

0
```

On giving next input 32

```
DONE 
32

0

0

0

0
```

Comment: You'll have to call `push` for every element.

Comment: You're using scanf only once in your main... How do you get your second input ?

Comment: Yes. Thnku for your answer. I looped scanf and push function. thnku for suggesting.
  for(int i=0; i<CAPACITY ; i++){
        scanf("%d", &element);
        push(element);
        
    }

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem, instead of correcting the code in comment. Post the *exact* code with copy/paste, not "something like" it. As posted, it looks as though you run the code twice and expect the stack to still hold a value from the first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest return `1` if you can push, and `0` if you can't **(stack full)**

```
int push(int element) {
    if(isfull()){
        printf("STACK IS FULL\n");

        return 0; // Stack is full
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = element;
        printf("DONE\n");

        return 1;// stack is not full 
    }
}
```

- In `main()` function ask user to enter a number until stack is full
- The loop stops when push returns `0`, that is **stack is full**

```
int main(){
    // loop starts here
    // Enter a number first before checking if stack is full 

    do
    {scanf("%d", &element);}

    while(push(element));// Stop if stack is full  
                        //otherwise push element inside the Stack


    for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++){
        printf("\n%d\n", stack[i]);
    }

}
```